# Cannot access values of a multidimensional list groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to access the values of a list;

```
totalList:[[0], [22]]
```

I wanted to get each values, but it kept throwing me : 
Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object

when I'm trying it following way,

```
println "totList: " + totalList[0][0]
```

Comment: you're setting to `totList` but reading from `totalList`

Comment: My mistake it's totalList anyway thanks for pointing that out I have already edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample you've provided, you should not be receiving any errors. This script works just fine:

```
totalList = [[0], [22]]
println "totList: " + totalList[0][0]
```

The output is `totList: 0`.

Comment: You are right! At one point my list gets empty, that's why I got the above error. Thanks...